# Gulp Sourcemaps path

Tags: gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I am trying to use gulp-sourcemaps to generate source map.

Example code:

```
gulp.task('compressjs', function() {
    gulp.src(['public/js/**/*.js','!public/js/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({
        extname: '.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

The output of the path is `//# sourceMappingURL=/script.min.js.map`, which is the wrong path. The correct one should be `//# sourceMappingURL=script.min.js.map`. How can I remove that extra `/` in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sourcemaps.write('.')` to write the map file to same directory as js file.

Also the first `.pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))` is not necessary.